# Two tick labels overlap in the plot with symlog scale

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have made a plot with `symlog` on x-axis, and intend to make the linear region short enough (`linscalex = 0.2`). Please see my graph. However, the first tick label (1e-2) of the log region overlaps with the origin (0). Is there anyway to remove the tick label 1e-2?

Here is my code

```
plt.xscale('symlog', linthreshx = 0.05, 
           subsx = range(2,10), linscalex = 0.2)
```

[image]

Comment: What would be the desired outcome? Remove the 0?

Comment: I would prefer remove 1e-2, Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you can set the ticks via `plt.gca().set_xticks([0,.1,1,10])`?

Comment: Thank you @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, it fixes my problem. But I am wondering if there is a more general way? Like automatically remove the second tick label of `symlog` despite other labels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @ImportanceOfBeingErnest noted in the comments, you can simply set the ticks explicitly with

```
plt.gca().set_xticks([0, .1, 1, 10])
```

But since you ask for a more general solution, I thought to provide one - you can get the existing xticks and simply remove the second one indiscriminately with the following (probably a way to collapse this into a one-liner)

```
ticks = plt.xticks()[0]
ticks[1] = ticks[0]
plt.xticks(ticks[1:])
```

Obviously this is a bit of a blunt approach as it will *always* remove the second label, even if it isn't interfering.